# Как выполнить проверку на NaN?

Tags: javascript, проверка, nan

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь выполнить проверку на `NaN`, но что-то я делаю не так *(см. закомментированный код.)*

В коде ниже нужно реализовать, чтобы при вводе в `<input type="text" id="rub" />` нечислового значения, выводился результат в `<input type="text" id="usd" readonly />` "Введите число".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>31</title>
    <style>
        .block {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        label, input {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <label for="rub">RUB</label>
        <input type="text" id="rub" />
        <label for="usd">USD</label>
        <input type="text" id="usd" readonly />
    </div>
    <script>
    'use strict';

let inputRub = document.querySelector('#rub'),
    inputUsd = document.querySelector('#usd');

inputRub.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'thirtyOne.json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    request.send();

    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == 200) {
            let data = JSON.parse(request.response);

            inputUsd.value = (inputRub.value / data.usd).toFixed(2);
        }
        // else if (isNaN(inputRub.value) === true) {
        //     inputUsd.value = 'Введите число';
        // }
        else {
            inputUsd.value = 'Что-то пошло не так =(';
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: какая-то странная логика. `readyState` меняется несколько раз в обработчике и каждый раз будет вызываться функция и проверяться значение на isNaN

Comment: скорее всего просто проверку надо вынести из обработчика, и если она не прошла не запускать запрос

Comment: @Grundy, запрос вообще не надо запускать из обработчика...

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему не надо? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, а что ему там делать на каждую клавишу? Так часто курс валют меняется? И даже если да, то неизвестно, какой ответ придёт последним.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну это уже другой вопрос :-) debounce и все :-) в любом же случае в обработчике будет :)

Comment: @Grundy, откуда он там будет, если в коде видно, что его нет?

Comment: Я имел ввиду добавить :-) но это ж все равно внутри обработчика будет :-)